# Facebook like box - Could not retrieve the specified page?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Question:

I have copied the below code from [here](http://www.xeniaonline.com). 
Now I altered the appid to mine, and the username to MyUserName.
If I only alter the appid, then it works, when I change the username to 
MyUserName, then it displays this error:

```
Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.
```

If I put in the URL `http://www.facebook.com/MyUser.Name` in my browser,  then it shows the profile correctly.

Is there anything I have to switch in the facebook profile ?

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


...



<div id="facebook-box">
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-faces="false" data-height="100" data-width="220" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/MyUserName">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the message accurate? are you passing a URL which doesn't represent a Facebook Page?

Comment: If I copy-paste the URL, it shows the facebook page ...

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling where you're wrong,you are passing your FB profile URL which is wrong.You need to provide the URL of the facebook page(that you want to like) instead of  the URL of your profile,
try the below code:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-faces="false" data-height="100" data-width="220" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/the URL of the Facebook Page you want to like">
```

Comment: Unlikely, else it wouldn't work on profile1, but not on profile2. It works if I use fb-like instead of fb-like-box, but then it doesn't show the profile picture, besides, the facebook profile is also a facebook page, just like any other page. It is some other problem.